# Google Analytics Hit Quotas

Tags: google-analytics

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I have a user who under a specific property, sporadically receives the following error:

*Some hits sent on 03-Jul-2018 to property ...... exceeded one or more hit quotas and were therefore not processed.
Hits can be dropped when daily or monthly hit limits are exceeded. You can view your hit volume levels in Property Settings in Analytics.
Hits can also be dropped if visitor hit limits are exceeded. This can happen when your site is incorrectly generating the visitor ID for a GA session. Contact your website administrator to check that the visitor ID generation has been correctly implemented.*

They are not using the Premium account but when I look at the data for the day in question, there aren't any issues with regards to 'High Cardinality' which unless I've misunderstood I'd expect to see.

Could someone look at this please and offer some guidance where the issue may be because this area is fairly new to me.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: Won't this hits limitations about the maximum size of the payload... which is 8192 characters or 8192 bytes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Collection limits are influenced by 2 factors**:

- `The tracker`: whether you use `ga.js`,`gtag.js`,`analytics.js` etc... [here are the details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas#universal_properties).
- `The property type`: whether you are using `GA` ([10M hits / month](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas#non-premium)) or `GA 360` ([2B hits / month](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency)).

**In your case you are facing a property limit**. To find out when such limits where reached, you can create a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) using a [time dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_date) (eg date+time) combined with the [hits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_hits) metric. You can also combine the hit metrics with other dimensions (country, browser, device) to see if you find any patterns as to why you're getting so many hits.

**Cardinality is something else**: it refers to the number of unique value combinations for your dimensions. For instance if you have 500K events where each event category is different, you'll have a Cardinality of 500K on the event category dimension. The more hits, the more likely you'll have a high cardinality, but the 2 aren't necessary related (if you send 10B events with the same category, the cardinality on the category is 1).

**So focus on identifying and solving your limits/quotas issue**, as it's the real issue here:

- If the number of hits is legitimate (you have a huge amount of traffic), then the only options are to upgrade to GA 360 or reduce the number of hits for each session
- If the number of hits is abnormally high (eg traffic is stable but hits increased dramatically), look for implementation issues, especially generic event trackers such as error tracking with tools like Google Tag Manager